# How to create a javascript array to send data into this json format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am new to this so please bear with me.

Please guide me as to how to create a javascript array which in turn gives me a json like this.

```
{
"MotorInsurance": [{
    "Service": "Compare",
    "Data": [{
        "Apikey": "1234",
        "Process": "Compare",
        "TransactionId": "32",
        "Type": "New",
        "Channel": "1"
    }],
    "Vehicle": [{
        "VehicleCode": "456",
        "RTOCode": "AP12",
        "RegistrationYear": "2016"
    }],
    "User":[{
         "IPAddress": "66",
         "DateTime": "12-06-2016"
    }]
}]

}
```

I have tried this :

```
var formData = {};
formData['MotorInsurance'] = {};
formData['MotorInsurance']['Service'] = "Compare";
formData['MotorInsurance']['Data'] = {};
formData['MotorInsurance']['Data']['Apikey'] = '1234';
formData['MotorInsurance']['Data']['Process'] = 'Compare';
formData['MotorInsurance']['Data']['TransactionId'] = '32';
formData['MotorInsurance']['Data']['Type'] = 'New';
formData['MotorInsurance']['Data']['Channel'] = '1';
formData['MotorInsurance']['Vehicle'] = {};
formData['MotorInsurance']['Vehicle']['VehicleCode'] = '';
formData['MotorInsurance']['Vehicle']['RTOCode'] = '';
formData['MotorInsurance']['Vehicle']['RegistrationYear'] = '';
formData['MotorInsurance']['User'] = {};
formData['MotorInsurance']['User']['IPAddress'] = '66.12.5.4';
formData['MotorInsurance']['User']['DateTime'] = '12-06-2016';
```

Please guide me. Thanks

Comment: What you have in the first example is an object. If you want to turn that in to JSON, just call `JSON.stringify` on it: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/qqko91yg/

Comment: `MotorInsurance`, `Data`, `Vehicle` and `User` are arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var formData = {};
formData['MotorInsurance'] = [{}];
formData['MotorInsurance'][0]['Service'] = "Compare";
formData['MotorInsurance'][0]['Data'] = [{}];
formData['MotorInsurance'][0]['Data'][0]['Apikey'] = '1234';
formData['MotorInsurance'][0]['Data'][0]['Process'] = 'Compare';
formData['MotorInsurance'][0]['Data'][0]['TransactionId'] = '32';
formData['MotorInsurance'][0]['Data'][0]['Type'] = 'New';
formData['MotorInsurance'][0]['Data'][0]['Channel'] = '1';
formData['MotorInsurance'][0]['Vehicle'] = [{}];
formData['MotorInsurance'][0]['Vehicle'][0]['VehicleCode'] = '';
formData['MotorInsurance'][0]['Vehicle'][0]['RTOCode'] = '';
formData['MotorInsurance'][0]['Vehicle'][0]['RegistrationYear'] = '';
formData['MotorInsurance'][0]['User'] = [{}];
formData['MotorInsurance'][0]['User'][0]['IPAddress'] = '66.12.5.4';
formData['MotorInsurance'][0]['User'][0]['DateTime'] = '12-06-2016';
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(formData, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `formData['MotorInsurance']` has to be an array:

```
formData['MotorInsurance'] = [];
```

Then you'll be creating everything else in the first element of this array:

```
formData['MotorInsurance'][0] = {};
formData['MotorInsurance'][0]['Service'] = "Compare";
```

The same goes for `Data`, `Vehicule` and `User`.

Answer (score 0):

You can approach it like this: for the nested objects, populate them one by one (like the data variable below) and then when assigning to the form data, make sure you put square brackets around the variable.

```
vehicle = {
  "VehicleCode": "456",
  "RTOCode": "AP12",
  "RegistrationYear": "2016"
};

user = {
  "IPAddress": "66",
  "DateTime": "12-06-2016"
};

data = {
  "Apikey": "1234",
  "Process": "Compare",
  "TransactionId": "32",
  "Type": "New",
  "Channel": "1"
};

service = {"Service": "Compare"}

o = {"Data": [data], "Vehicle": [vehicle], "User": [user], "Service": service}

formData["MotorInsurance"] = [o]
```